# How to create this effect using Geometry Nodes

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, geometry-nodes

I am trying to recreate this effect using geometry nodes. I am currently using Particle Properties to fill the model with cubes however I would like to regulate the cubes so they don't intersect as much. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you want them to be symmetrical or random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a setup like this - For the *Distribute Points on Faces* node, make sure to use *Poisson Disk* - this lets you set a minimum "gap" space between instances:

[image: Poisson]

Comment: Hi, this works great when applying to a plane/cube however it doesn't work when applying to a mesh created from an imported SVG or any imported models. Only 1 large cube is visible. Thanks

Comment: This works on quad based faces, however meshes made from imported SVG's (and other imported models) are often wrought with tri's (triangle faces) - for these, you will have to find a way to covert the mesh into quads, then it _should_ work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using this method:

[image]